# How to express a counting process in terms of respective arrival process and interarrival process?

Tags: poisson-process, renewal-processes

Suppose that $N=\{N_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is a counting process that counts the number of events by time $t$, $T=\{T_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is an arrival time process, i.e., the time at which an event happens, and $W=\{W_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$ is an interarrival process, i.e., the time between consecutively arriving events. Concerning the event that exactly $n$ events have occurred by time $t$, we know that

\begin{equation}
\{N_t= n\} = \{T_n \leq t\} \cap \{W_{n+1}> t- T_{n}\} 
\end{equation}

Now, I would like to know how we can represent the event that between $n_1$ and $n_2$ events have occurred by time $t$, i.e., $\{n_1 \leq N_t \leq n_2\}$, based on events constructed by process $T$ and $W$. More precisely, if it is possible to find a representation like the foregoing one in this case?

\begin{equation}
\{n_1\leq N_t \leq n_2\} = ?
\end{equation}

Comment: The interarrival times obscure what is happening here.  I'd advise you to rewrite $\{W_{n+1}> t- T_{n}\}$ as $\{T_{n+1}> t\}$.  Try to understand this.  Then go back to your question and write it just in terms of $T$, not $W$.

Comment: You are right, but I need to take into account the interarrival time in my representation for some reason. However, as you mentioned, it can make it easier if I just write in terms of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{ {n_1 \leq N_t \leq n_2} \} = \{ T_{n_1} \leq t  \} \cap \{  \sum_{i = 1}^{n2-n1+1} W_{n_1 + i} \geq t-T_{n_1}\}$$
Reduces to the standard form if $n_2 = n_1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. Can I ask how you prove this relation?

Comment: Is it possible to find a simpler representation that does not consider a sum operator? I do appreciate your time.

Comment: If you don't want a sum operator, you will need to represent it as $T_{n_2}$, as pointed out by Brian. The proof also becomes evident if you use this as $\Sigma W_i + T_{n_1}$ is nothing but $T_{n_2}$. You will need a sum over inter-arrival times otherwise. At least for the most general form.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I got it.